# How to load data from github graphql using since like rest API

Tags: github, graphql, pipeline, github-issues, incremental-load

I have written a pipeline to load issues from GitHub to big query; I want to make it incremental, for example, load only the data from the last run to the present run; I tweaked the pipeline code to pass since arg, but I don't know if the `graphql` supports it or not. Or is there a different way to load data incrementally using `graphql`? We would have to surely pass the variable to query to retrieve only the data needed.

here is how query starts

```
ISSUES_QUERY = """
query($owner: String!, $name: String!, $issues_per_page: Int!, $first_reactions: Int!, $first_comments: Int!, $page_after: String) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    %s(first: $issues_per_page, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}, after: $page_after) {
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        startCursor
      }
      nodes {
        id
```

If anyone can suggest how to pass since parameter or if `graphql` supports since parameter of not it'd be great. Thanks

```
ISSUES_QUERY = """
query($owner: String!, $name: String!, $issues_per_page: Int!, $first_reactions: Int!, $first_comments: Int!, $page_after: String, since: String) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    %s(first: $issues_per_page, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}, after: $page_after, since: $since) {
      totalCount
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        startCursor
      }
      nodes {
        id
        number
```

I Got this error

> In processing pipe issues: extraction of resource issues in generator _get_reactions_data caused an exception: {'errors': [{'path': ['query', 'repository', 'issues', 'since'], 'extensions': {'code': 'argumentNotAccepted', 'name': 'issues', 'typeName': 'Field', 'argumentName': 'since'}, 'locations': [{'line': 4, 'column': 104}], 'message': "Field 'issues' doesn't accept argument 'since'"}, {'path': ['query'], 'extensions': {'code': 'variableNotUsed', 'variableName': 'since'}, 'locations': [{'line': 2, 'column': 1}], 'message': 'Variable $since is declared by anonymous query but not used'}]}

Comment: GraphQL on its own doesn't have any semantics like what you describe.  If the schema supports some sort of `since` field argument then you can use it.  The `Field 'issues' doesn't accept argument 'since'` suggests this may not be an option in this particular API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you page backwards in time until you get an issue whose `createdDate` is earlier than your `since` criteria. There is no `since` filter in the GitHub [issueConnection](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#issueconnection) type.

Please not also that issues can be *updated* at any time so this approach won't work for catching *updates* to issues.